# There's a way to save a XML without displaying the Dialog Box?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, archive

I just created a xml editor in Flex that works perfectly, but i'm having trouble with save option. In fact he's saving quite well, the problem is that it is displaying a dialog box for saving the document, and i want to save and replace the file automatically when i click the save button without displaying the dialog box.
Can anyone help me with this?

NOTE: I am using the FileReference class to use the method Save(), i read somewhere on the internet that FileStream class can be used for this, but i don't know how...

Well, anyway...
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) class is only available when developing an AIR application. The code would be something along this:

```
_file = new File("path_to_file_in_filesystem");
_loader = new URLLoader();
_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _loadingComplete);

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("path_to_file_on_web");
_loader.load(req);      

private function _loadingComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(_file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(_loader.data);
    fs.close();
    fs = null;
    _loader.unload();           
    _loader = null;
}
```

There is no way to save a file into the filesystem without users permission in web player.